# Rails mailboxer gem cannot send message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am using Mailboxer gem for the messaging function, but as I am very new I am not very sure how to use it. Basically I created the following message controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_message, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    current_user.send_message(@recipient, message_params(:body, :subject))
    redirect_to conversations_path
  end

  private

  def set_message
    @recipient = User.find(params[:recipient_id])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

Then my view:

```
<h1>New Message</h1>

<%= simple_form_for(@message, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :subject %>
  <%= f.input :body, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "3"} %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But I can't send message...
(BTW I can send message is the console, and also replace part of the message controller with "current_user.send_message(@recipient, "test", "test")", but definitely not what I want)

Comment: Also it would be handy if you post the exact stack error that you are getting...

Comment: Have you figured out the answer to this?  Im trying to do it now and I get the error that i have an undefined model name.  I don't understand though because shouldn't the gem take care of that?  Do we need to make messages model?  If so, what would need to go in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Use form_tag instead of form_for**

Instead of using form_for, try using form_tag, as this has worked for me:

```
<%= form_tag("/messages/send_message", method: "post", url: send_message_path) do  %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, "#{@user.id}" %>
<%= text_field_tag :subject, nil, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Subject" %>
<%= text_area_tag :message, nil, :class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Message" %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This would have an action you messages controller like this:

```
def send_message
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@message = params[:message]
@subject = params[:subject]
current_user.send_message(@user, "#{@message}", "#{@subject}")
redirect_to root_path
end
```

And something like this in you routes file:

```
post '/messages/send_message', :to => "messages#send_message", :as => "send_message"
```

Really hope this helps!